# Detect AJAX requests in browser (Detect Google Analytics requests)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

A am trying detect all AJAX rquests in my browser. 
I am using this code:

```
function addXMLRequestCallback(callback) {
    var oldSend, i;

    if( XMLHttpRequest.callbacks ) {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push( callback );
    } else {
        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
        oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
        XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function() {
            for( i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++ ) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i]( this );
            }
            oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
}
​
addXMLRequestCallback( function( xhr ) {
    console.log( xhr.responseText ); // (an empty string)
});
addXMLRequestCallback( function( xhr ) {
    console.dir( xhr ); // have a look if there is anything useful here
});
```

But this is code don't work with detecting Google Analytics events. (For example: `ga('send', 'event', 'Videos', 'play', 'Fall Campaign');`)
Is there any solution to detect the sending of Google events?
**Note: without extensions.**  Thanks.

Comment: Why not just use devtools in Chrome ?

Comment: @Dabbas I need to do this automatically on remote computers.

Comment: I think I understand why I can't detect google events. Google traces events using pixel tracking.  :(